# twitteR search geocode argument in R

Tags: r, search, twitter

I want to run a simple search using twitteR but only return tweets located in the U.S. I know twitteR has a geocode argument for lat/long and miles within that lat/long, but this way of locating tweets for an entire country seems hard.

What would I input into the argument to only get US tweets?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a brief search around and it looks like twitteR does not have a built-in country argument. But since you have lat/long, it's very straightforward to do a spatial join to a US country shapefile (i.e. point in polygon).

In this example, I'm using the [shapefile from Census.gov](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_nation.html) and the package **spatialEco** for its `point.in.polygon()` function. It's a very fast spatial-join function compared to what other packages offer, even if you have hundreds of thousands of coordinates and dozens of polygons. If you have millions of tweets -- or if you decide later on to join to multiple polygons, e.g. all world countries -- then it could be a lot slower. But for most purposes, it's very fast.

(Also, I don't have a Twitter API set up, so I'm going to use an example data frame with tweet_ids and lat/long.)

```
library(maptools) # to 
library(spatialEco)

# First, use setwd() to set working directory to the folder called cb_2015_us_nation_20m
us <- readShapePoly(fn = "cb_2015_us_nation_20m")
# Alternatively, you can use file.choose() and choose the .shp file like so:
us <- readShapePoly(file.choose())

# Create data frame with sample tweets
# Btw, tweet_id 1 is St. Louis, 2 is Toronto, 3 is ouston
tweets <- data.frame(tweet_id = c(1, 2, 3), 
                 latitude = c(38.610543, 43.653226, 29.760427),
                 longitude = c(-90.337189, -79.383184, -95.369803))

# Use point.in.poly to keep only tweets that are in the US
coordinates(tweets) <- ~longitude+latitude
tweets_in_us <- point.in.poly(tweets, us)
tweets_in_us <- as.data.frame(tweets_in_us)
```

Now, if you look at `tweets_in_us` you should see only the tweets whose lat/long fall within the area of the US.